# Spark splitting a DStream into several RDDs

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

The same question also applies to splitting an RDD into several new RDDs.

A DStream or RDD contains several different case classes and I need to turn them into separate RDDs based on case class type.

I'm aware of

```
val newRDD = rdd.filter { a => a.getClass.getSimpleName == "CaseClass1" }
```

or

```
val newRDD = rdd.filter { 
  a => a match { 
    case _: CC1 => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

But this requires many runs through the original RDD, one per case class type.

1. There must be a more concise way to do the above matching filter?
2. Is there a way to split an rdd into several by the element type with one parallel pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like with `rdd.filter` I was on the right track with the long form. A slightly more concise version is:

```
val newRDD = rdd.filter { case _: CC1 => true ; case _ => false }
```

You can't leave out the `case _ => false` or the test for class is not exhaustive and you'll get errors. I couldn't get the collect to work correctly.

@maasg gets credit for the right answer about doing separate filter passes rather than hacking a way to split input in one pass.

Answer (score 4):

1) A more concise way of filtering for a given type is to use `rdd.collect(PartialFunction[T,U])`

The equivalent of

```
val newRDD = rdd.filter { a => a.getClass.getSimpleName == "CaseClass1" }
```

would be:

```
val newRDD = rdd.collect{case c:CaseClass1 => c}
```

It could even be combined with additional filtering and transformation:

```
val budgetRDD = rdd.collect{case c:CaseClass1 if (c.customer == "important") => c.getBudget}
```

**`rdd.collect(p:PartialFunction[T,U])` *should not* be confused with `rdd.collect()` which delivers data back to the driver.**

---

2) To split an RDD (or a DStream for that matter), `filter` is the way to go. One must remember that an RDD is a distributed collection. Filter will let you apply a function to a subset of that distributed collection, in parallel, over the cluster.

A structural creation of 2 or more RDDs from an original RDD would incur a 1-to-many shuffle stage, which will be substantially more expensive.

Comment: OK, but I don't really want to collect do I? I edited the above to assign the returned filter to an rdd. In other words I do want a filter, right?

Comment: I guess it's because returning a value from the closure is easier than a Boolean?

Comment: edited the answer to show that the call returns an RDD. As I mentioned, rdd.collect() and rdd.collect{case x => x.y} have two very different purposes.